# /_layouts/15/closeconnection.aspx?signinasanotheruser=true (Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site, login, share, connection

I am site collection administrator and can access all the sites in my web app. But when I want to change login as another user like below:

```
http://testing:10020/_layouts/15/closeconnection.aspx?signinasanotheruser=true
```

, then I see this error message:`Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.`

How I share this site?

Answer (score 4):

i think your URL is different then MSFT recommended. Please use the below mentioned URL then try it.

```
http://testing:10020/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true
```

[Read more about it over here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2752600)